# Этапы создания компьютерной игры на Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Пишу компьютерную игру, но не знаю чего не хватает, т.к. собираю информацию в Youtube по незаконченным авторами курсам. Какие этапы разработки я узнал из роликов:

- Прототипирование (Выбор жанра, сеттинга, герои, механика, концепт-арты, локации из примитивов и т.д.)
- Написание игры (вот здесь у меня знания неполные)
- Тестирование (Отлов багов, проверка работоспособности всех функций и т.д.)
- Релиз с последующим сопровождением

Как я понимаю этот процесс (написание игры):

- Создаем 3D модели (опираемся на концепт-арты, прототипы локаций из примитивов)
- Если модель - персонаж, создаем анимацию.
- Импортируем модели в Unity
- Настраиваем материалы для моделей в Unity
- Расставляем готовые модели (prefab'ы) по сцене.
- Пишем скрипты для взаимодействия между объектами.
- Пишем систему для инвентаря игрока.
- Пишем систему для сохранения игры.
- *Огромный пробел в знаниях* (что еще нужно сделать?)
- Создаем главное меню.
- Собираем екзешник.

Просьба дополнить мой список или написать свой.

Comment: Тут нет конкретный список. Во время создания может случится такое о чего вы даже думать не смогли. Например такая проблема с оптимизацией что вам придётся изменить свою идею.

Comment: Ещё это зависит от типа игры от внешнего вида от размера вашей команды и. т. д.

Comment: А если всё таки список хотите то ваш список довольно хороший

Comment: Делать все по подобным шагам - адовый шок контент, почитай немного про методики ведения проектов.

Comment: @yolosora почему шок? Я обобщил этапы, разделение на подэтапы с промежуточным тестирование, назначением ответственных лиц  опущены.

Answer (score 4):

Стоит добавить информацию о методологиях разработки. Пошерсти информацию какими бывают.

То есть тестирование идет не обязательно после разработки игры (ватерфолл), но может идти и во время и, даже, ДО начала разработки.

Окроме работы с 3д моделями по артах практически наверняка нужно будет выделить время на написание шейдеров, а так же на применение пост-эфектов на камеру.

Левел-дизайн - это огромная часть создания игры. От правильного левел-дизайна много чего зависит. Даже сам процесс программирования может быть завязан на левел-дизайн. Не говоря уже про особенности игрового процесса.

Если игра имеет определенные особенности с анимацией, то анимация продумывается до начала игрового процесса в видеоредакторе. (примером игры является Ori and Blind Forest)

Так же нужно определится под какое железо нужно пилять. Минимальные требования определяют то, что должно получится в результате. А так же определяют спектр/границы оптимизации.

Так же нужно видеть свою аудиторию и определить способы монетизации. Возраст, пол, заработок и т.д. Чем четче определишь аудиторию тем лучше игру под нее сможешь заточить. И тем более точные способы монетизации подберешь. А так же это напрямую влияет на рекламную кампанию.